# how to display image on ultra tree node?

Tags: c#, infragistics

I am using Infragistics ultrawin tree and assigning data source to it. i want to display images from data source on left side and right side of ultra tree node.  Datatable will be in below format

```
UserImage  UserID  StatusImage
 Image1        1      image4
 Image2        2      image5
 Image3        3      image6
```

UserImage will dispaly before node and UserId will be dispaly as text and StatusImage will display after  node text. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is what you want but here it goes and it's in VB you should be able to convert this to C#

i am using an imagelist for this and the tree is unbound

```
    Dim utNode As New UltraTreeNode

    utNode.Text = UltraTree1.Nodes.Count + 1

    utNode.LeftImages.Add(Me.ImageList1.Images((UltraTree1.Nodes.Count) Mod 5))

    utNode.RightImages.Add(Me.ImageList1.Images((UltraTree1.Nodes.Count) Mod 5))

    UltraTree1.Nodes.Add(utNode)
```

this will give you image on the left and on the right with the numbers as nodetext

put this code behind a button's event and create an imagelist with 5 images that's it

hope it helps

Comment: i am assigning data source to ultratree. How i will show the image on ultra tree node.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody needs it, I have figured out how to place left icons on bounded UltraTree:

Using the InitializeDataNode event, the Icon can be added like the following code (in my case, imagelist contains images named exactly the same as nodes text):

```
private void treeMDI_InitializeDataNode(object sender, InitializeDataNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.LeftImages.Count == 0)
            if (imgÍconos.Images[e.Node.Text] != null)
                e.Node.LeftImages.Add(imgÍconos.Images[e.Node.Text]);
    }
```

The second **if** sentence is just to find out if the image exists on imagelist. When all images were available I removed it.